# Android fragment transition custom view

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-animation, android-custom-view

I want to create a custom animation for fragment transition. The animation is in form of a circle that increases his radius from a specific size until it is equal to window height. I can use **ScaleAnimation**, but then I'll lose drawable quality. Does someone have any ideas ho to do this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I'll answer my own question :). To animate the fragment transition with my custom transition (a colored circle that increases his size) I have done the following:
 - create a custom view that draws a circle and add the possibility to increase his radius;
 - place this view in my **FragmentActivity** xml layout;
 - when the target button is clicked and fragment should change I've called ValueAnimator to change circle radius;

Final code will look something like this:

```
public class MainScreenActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button targetButton;
    private CircleView circleView;



    public void targetButtonClick(View view) {
        AnimationHandler handler = new AnimationHandler(view.getX(),view.getY());
        handler.animate();
    }

    private class AnimationHandler implements Animator.AnimatorListener, ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener {
        private static final int TRANSITION_ANIM_DURATION = 500;
        private final float centerX;
        private final float centerY;
        private ValueAnimator valueAnimator;

        public AnimationHandler(float x, float y) {
            this.centerX = x;
            this.centerY = y;
            init();
        }

        private void init() {
            Point point = new Point();
            getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getSize(point);
            valueAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0, point.y);
            valueAnimator.setDuration(TRANSITION_ANIM_DURATION);
            valueAnimator.addUpdateListener(this);
            valueAnimator.addListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
            circleView.setRadius((float) animation.getAnimatedValue());
        }

        public void animate() {
            circleView.setXCenter(centerX);
            circleView.setYCenter(centerY);
            int color = getResources().getColor(android.R.color.dark_red);
            circleView.setStrokeWidth(getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.trans_circle_width));
            valueAnimator.start();
        }
    }
}
```